# MAUI: What is the difference between GoToAsync() and PushAsync() to navigate between pages?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I am trying to learn how is the best way to navigate between pages in a MAUI application and MVVM.

I have seen that in the examples from Microsoft, the default way to do it is with `PushAsync()`, but later I have seen that it is possible to navigate with `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()`.

Which is the difference between both? Or are they complementary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a sample to test the `PushAsync()` and `GoToAsync()`.

The `GoToAsync()` navigates between the current page and the target page according to the route. So it will not create multiple instances of the same page. One page only have one instance. And if you navigate such as Page1 -> Page2 with the `GoToAsync()`, you can't use the `GoToAsync()` go to Page1. You can only use `GoToAsync("..")` go to Page1.

But for the `PushAsync()`, you can use the `PushAsync(new Page2())` to create multiple instance of the same page. And the navigation stack will be like Page1 -> Page2 -> Page1 -> Page2...

So the `GoToAsync()` is like the `PushAsync()` with the singleton page. And you need to register the route when you use the `GoToAsync()`.

In addition, when you use `GoToAsync()` to navigate, there are some limits, such as you can pass a collection data to the next page. But when you use the `PushAsync()`, you can pass almost all types of the data to target page.

Generally speaking, the `PushAsync()` is easy to use and pass data and the `GoToAsync()` has the better function but needs more details.

Comment: But with goToAsync() you can get new instances each time you navigate, if you register the service builder.Services.AddTransient() in the MauiProgram class. Registration it is a way to use dependency injection for the instantiation of the pages.

Comment: But when I test the `goToAsync()`, it will not create multiple instances of the same page.

Comment: Nice and clear explanation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that PushAsync() is not longer available to navigate with Shell, you should use GotoAsync().

But PushAsync is related to stack the page over the other ones so you can later pop and navigate back to the page. GotoAsync() use relatives to navigate, you can check the documentation here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Yes, it is what I realized with some code example. If I use PushAsync() and I click the arrow to back in a page, I go to the previews page because of the stack pages. If I do the same when GoToAsync() it is used, I back to the root page. But I guess this can be fix when I set the routing in the AppShell flie.